# Express - req.ip returns 127.0.0.1

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, proxy

I have my express server running on port 3000 with nginx for the reverse proxy.

req.ip always returns 127.0.0.1 and req.ips returns an empty array

`app.enable('trust proxy');`

With/without enabling trust proxy, x-forwarded-for doesn't work:

```
var ip_addr = req.headers['X-FORWARDED-FOR'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
```

nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/dev_localhost.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

How do i get the IP address of the requesting client?

Comment: What does your nginx config look like?

Comment: Added nginx configuration

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to pass the appropriate `X-Forwarded-For` header to your upstream. Add these lines to your upstream config:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

Comment: This works! It's working on my server. But its still printing 127.0.0.1 on localhost

Comment: If you're connecting to `localhost` from `localhost` what else would you expect?

Comment: Not Working for me

Comment: var ip  = (req.headers["cf-connecting-ip"]) ? req.headers["cf-connecting-ip"] : 'unknown'; if any of you are using cloudflare

Comment: can't figure out how to get the request headers set in nginx conf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51265803/nginx-proxy-set-header-does-not-pass-req-header-to-backend-undefined-req-heade

Comment: this is frustrating to test on localhost, it seems to not check the x-forwarded-for on local requests, but i'm trying to spoof a request through our stack while developing locally... am i correct or going mad?

Answer (score 13):

According to the express documentation:

> [**Express behind proxies**](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html)
>
> When running an Express app behind a proxy, set (by using app.set()) the application variable trust proxy to one of the values listed in the following table.

You can set it to a boolean, ip address, number or a custom function. If you want to just get the client's proxy to your express app's ***req.ip***, you can just set it to true.

```
app.set('trust proxy',true); 
app.get("/", (req, res)=>{
    console.log(req.ip); 
});
```